# How to write SQL result to JSON

Tags: java, sql, json, gson, writer

I have successfully written code that writes the first record of the SQL result set in JSON using Google GSON.

Unfortunately, when the result set has more than 1 record it throws the following exception:

> JSON must have only one top-level value

Here is my code:

```
HttpServletResponse httpres = response;
httpres.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
httpres.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            httpres.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

while (rs.next()) {
  writer.beginObject();
  // loop rs.getResultSetMetadata columns
  for (int idx = 1; idx <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); idx++) {
    writer.name(rsmd.getColumnLabel(idx)); // write key:value pairs
    writer.value(rs.getString(idx));
  }
  writer.endObject();
}

writer.close();
httpres.getOutputStream().flush();
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: use writer.beginArray() FYR http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonWriter.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code will generate JSON that looks like this:

```
{
   "foo":"bar"
},
{
   "foo":"baz"
},
{
   "foo":"quux"
}
```

However, [this is not valid JSON](http://www.json.org/); you can't have commas unless you are **inside an object or an array**.

However, if you add `beginArray` and `endArray`, your code will become this:

```java
writer.beginArray();
while(rs.next()) { 
  // snip... no changes to your code
}
writer.endArray();
```

Which will make your JSON look like this:

```
[ 
  {
     "foo":"bar"
  },
  {
     "foo":"baz"
  },
  {
     "foo":"quux"
  }
]
```

Which **is** valid JSON, and will fix your problem.